# Node application delivering Vue.js frontend as well: how to support Vue dev server while development?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have a typical Vue.js application with a NodeJS backend. For authentication purposes (in this case: CAS) I decided to deliver the frontend via backend. In other words:

- on the target server, there is only one application (the Node server)
- routes beginning with `/api/` will serve backend routes (e.g. REST API for the frontend)
- routes beginning with `/client/` will serve the client as static content from the `client` directory on the server

Prior to this setup I used to have:

- a Node server serving the REST API
- a folder in the (Apache) web server's Document Root which delivers the Vue.js frontend (as static HTML/JS/CSS files)

The big advantage of the "one server" setup compared to "having Apache and Node" is that the CAS authentication process can be handled by the backend on its own whenever the client is requested. When the CAS login is finished successfully, the user is registered in the Node session and the request to `/client/` is accepted.

So, the Vue.js application does not have to deal in any way with authentication, it only has to get the current user from the backend, since it is guaranteed that there *IS* a valid session as soon as the user sees the client in the browser.

This works well on the server. But my **problem** is: how can I benefit from the hot-swap Vue.js dev server while developing when I am using this setup? The Node backend is unable to cooperate with the Vue.js dev server - let me explain why:

The `npm run serve` Vue.js dev server understands the Vue.js component files (*.vue) and unpacks them dynamically (I admit I have no idea how the dev server really accomplishes its tasks) and serves the pages. So, there *are* no real JS files to serve. So, the Node server is unable to serve anything useful when the client has been requested because all happens "under the hood" of the dev server.

I let my mind wander and e.g. thought of:

- starting the Vue.js dev server (`npm run serve`)
- configure the Node Express app to *not* use static content for the client, but a *reverse proxy* forwarding to the Vue.js dev server

Sounds a little bit too much and too tricky.

Has anybody used such a setup and solved this issue? I am shy of introducing too much of special statements only for development mode in the Node app . .. did I miss an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You use a proxy, which is supported out of the box.

> If your frontend app and the backend API server are not running on the
>   same host, you will need to proxy API requests to the API server
>   during development. This is configurable via the devServer.proxy
>   option in vue.config.js.
>
> devServer.proxy can be a string pointing to the development API
>   server:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
  }
}
```

> This will tell the dev server to proxy any unknown requests (requests
>   that did not match a static file) to http://localhost:4000.

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Comment: Ah interesting - did not know about this. But in my use case the server must *intercept* any client requests, so that the CAS auth process can "chime in" and do the auth work and *then* continue to process the client request. So it's the other way round: not the client should proxy "other" requests to the backend (for which I could use the `devServer` setting), but the backend must jump right in during client requests in case we are unauthorized.

Comment: Ah sorry. I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying.